# RegExp to test Full Name not working as expected

Tags: regex, vba, ms-access

I'm writing a VBA function to evaluate whether a String is a Valid Full Name or not. For example:

- Válid Full Name:

> David Gilmour
>
> Juan Munoz
>
> Claudio Alberto da Silva

- Invalid Full Name:

> David Gilm01ur Jr.
>
> Juan Muñoz
>
> Cláudio Alberto da Silva

So the code of my function is this:

```
Function isVálidoNome(ByVal Texto As String) As Boolean
isVálidoNome = False
'
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "(^[a-zA-Z]+(\s?[a-zA-Z])*)*"
'Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "\d"
Dim regularExpressions As New RegExp
'
regularExpressions.Pattern = strPattern
regularExpressions.Global = True
'
If (regularExpressions.Test(Texto)) Then
    isVálidoNome = True
End If


End Function
```

The pattern I used `(^[a-zA-Z]+(\s?[a-zA-Z])*)*` works fine in an app I used to test it (RegexPal), but when I run the code in VBA, Strings with digits, accents returns true

Why this problem or Did I make any mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bA3Imr/1)

Set `regularExpressions.Global = False`.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters
- `(?:` -  start of a non-capturing group matching zero or more (`*`) sequences of:

  - `\s` - a single whitespace (add `+` after it to match 1 or more whitespaces)
  - `[a-zA-Z]+`
- `)*` - end of the non-capturing group
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Man, it worked... But I'm still realizing: When I need a Regex expression depending of another, I have to use `(?:`, was this the cause of the problem, right?

Comment: `(?:...)` is just a *non*-capturing group. It is the same as a capturing one (`(...)`), but does not create `.Submatches`. Just makes the inner structure of the Match object cleaner.

Comment: Excuse for my question, but what is the difference between a capturing group and a non-capturing group? I read about it, but I'm still puzzled

Comment: It is explained well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon).

Comment: And the Global option, what is it for?

Comment: Global option is necessary to *extract* several matches from a single string. You are *validating*, you match the *whole string* against a single pattern. Hence, using Global option makes no sense.